# Executing shell script with system() returns 256. What does that mean?

Tags: c, linux, shell, daemon

I've written a shell script to soft-restart HAProxy (reverse proxy). Executing the script from the shell works. But I want a daemon to execute the script. That doesn't work. `system()` returns 256. I have no clue what that might mean.

```
#!/bin/sh
# save previous state
mv /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.old
mv /var/run/haproxy.pid /var/run/haproxy.pid.old

cp /tmp/haproxy.cfg.new /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
kill -TTOU $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid.old)
if haproxy -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -f /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg; then
  kill -USR1 $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid.old)
  rm -f /var/run/haproxy.pid.old
  exit 1
else
  kill -TTIN $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid.old)
  rm -f /var/run/haproxy.pid
  mv /var/run/haproxy.pid.old /var/run/haproxy.pid
  mv /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.err
  mv /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg.old /home/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
  exit 0
fi
```

HAProxy is executed with user haproxy. My daemon has it's own user too. Both run with sudo.

Any hints?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/113508-return-value-256/) and [that](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/usr/rgs/mosaic/pl-exp-sys.html), Perl's `system()` returns exit values multiplied by 256. So it's actually exiting with `1`. It seems [this happens in C too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808541/any-benefit-in-using-wexitstatus-macro-in-c-over-division-by-256-on-exit-status).

Comment: Thanks! So it's EPERM /* Operation not permitted */ ... but why ... I start the daemon with sudo.

Comment: Perl does not return multiplied exit values. It returns a 16 bit value, with the exit code in the higher 8 bits. It's often the same, but not always.

Comment: This also applies to most Linux/gcc binaries, not only Perl.

Answer (score 6):

Unless system returns -1 its return value is of the same format as the status value from the wait family of system calls (man 2 wait).  There are macros to help you interpret this status:

```
man 3 wait
```

Lists these macros and what they tell you.

Answer (score 4):

A code of 256 probably means that the system command cannot locate the binary to run it. Remember that it may not be calling bash and that it may not have paths setup. Try again with full paths to the binaries!

Comment: No. If it couldn't find the executable, it would return -1.

Comment: It could also happend it's an alias, and it could never find "the executable", so, what @mivk said is not accurate.

Always use full paths when spawning things...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when call script that contains `kill' command in a daemon.
The daemon must have closed the stdout, stderr...
Use something like system("scrips.sh > /dev/null") should work.