# Invoke a Java file using System() in c

Tags: java, c, web-services, perl

I am trying to run a java file that is sitting on my web server from c code. When I load the webpage, a perl script calls a c file which then calls the java file.

I have the call set up like in my c file:

```
System(java -cp <path> MyClass);
```

But this System() call returns 256 - (file not found I think).

I have also tried:

```
System(cd /<path> && java MyClass);
```

And get the same results.

If I run the exact same command from the terminal via ssh, it works fine, it is just when I try running the code from my browser that it gives this error.

Any ideas if my syntax is incorrect? Or am I doing something else wrong? Does it have something to do with the perl > c > java chain I am forced to use?

**EDIT** It appears that the c runtime was not looking at $PATH. I added the absolute path to java.exe, and it worked! Wooo

**tldr**

solution:

```
System("/opt/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/java -cp <path> MyClass");
```

Comment: Can't you just run `java -cp <path> MyClass` directly from the Perl script?

Comment: unfortunately not, because a bunch of data is generated from existing c code. So I need to do it this way unfortunately..

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736320/executing-shell-script-with-system-returns-256-what-does-that-mean), your error is actually being multiplied by 256, and your return is actually `1`.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code in your C file? (Not necessarily the entire C file, but the relevant parts as they appear in the C file) Because `System(java -cp <path> MyClass);` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: The code is just system(java -cp /theory/www/bin/tree MyClass);

Comment: You mean `system(java -cp /theory/www/bin/tree MyClass);` right?

Comment: yes, system not System

Comment: The normal way to solve this problem is to `fork()` and then `exec()` from the newly spawned process.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of trying to fork and exec. I was just hoping that this would work :) 

I will try that, thanks!

Comment: also, `system` is expecting a `string` right? Eg. `system("ls -l")`;

Comment: Yes, sorry it is a string

Comment: @Toadums Is it Linux or Windows system?

Comment: The server is running redhad

Comment: Did you check that the script is running with the appropriate rights? The `PATH` includes the binary path of `java` ... It may have a different configuration from yours.

Comment: You should try `system("pwd"); `system("echo $PATH");` to check that normal commands work, and find out where you are/what the `PATH` is.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and choose it instead of editing your question