# call system() return 256

Tags: c++, c, solaris

I want to system() to print pstack info in my application, but it failed and return 256.But I pick up these codes as below to one new main function,that's ok. why?

```
char cmd[256] ;
string pstackCmd;
struct timeval tv;
struct tm lt;(&tv, NULL);

localtime_r(&tv.tv_sec, &lt);
sprintf(cmd, "pstack `pgrep app` > pstack_%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%03d",
                            lt.tm_year+1900,
                            lt.tm_mon+1,
                            lt.tm_mday,
                            lt.tm_hour,
                            lt.tm_min,
                            lt.tm_sec,
                            (int)(tv.tv_usec/1000));
pstackCmd = string(cmd);
int retValue = system(pstackCmd.c_str());
if ( retValue != 0)
{
    printf("pstack `pgrep app`,retValue:%d",retValue);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing shell script with system() returns 256. What does that mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736320/executing-shell-script-with-system-returns-256-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: seems not, I build one new binary with these code, and run it in same directory.it can work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any benefit in using WEXITSTATUS macro in C over division by 256 on exit() status?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808541/any-benefit-in-using-wexitstatus-macro-in-c-over-division-by-256-on-exit-statu)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this:

```
if (retValue != 0)
```

You need this:

```
if (retValue == -1 || WEXITSTATUS(retValue) != 0)
```

That is, you check for failure first by seeing if `system()` returned -1; if it did not then the exit status of the command (with zero meaning success, traditionally).

Answer (score 3):

This mean that something went wrong and the command was not successfully executed. The return value `256` actually means `1`.

For more info check these link:

[System Return Code (was: 256)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=81640)

[system()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

```
If you'd like to manually inspect system's failure, you can check all possible failure modes by inspecting `$?` like this:

if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

Where `$? >> 8` is bitshifting by 8, which is essentially dividing by 256.

Comment: `>> 8` works perfect...I have a script that returns 1 and kept getting 256 in my c code that uses `system` to run the script. Now I receive what I expect..