# How can I get the return value of `wget` from a sh script into an `int` variable

Tags: c++, bash, shell, system

OS: Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
Board: Raspberry Pi 4

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

line=$(head -n 1 /var/www/html/configuration.txt)
file=/var/www/html/4panel/url_response.txt
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    wget_output=$(wget -q -i "$line" -O $file --timeout=2)
    echo "$?"
else
    echo > $file
    chown pi:pi $file 
fi
```

which I call from a C++ program using:

```
int val_system = 0;
val_system = system("/var/www/html/4panel/get_page.sh");
std::cout<<"System return value: "<<val_system<<std::endl;
```

If there is something wrong with the script, `echo "$?"` will output the return value of `wget`, but `val_system` will always be 0.

Does `system()` returns the value of `echo "$?"` ? In which case 0 is correct. And if that is the case how can I put the return value of `wget` in `val_system` ?

I have taken a situation in which `echo "$?"` always returns 8, basically I've entered an incorrect URL and:

- I have tried deleting `echo "$?"` but `val_system` still returned 0;
- With `echo "$?"` deleted I have changed the `wget` line to `wget -q -i "$line" -O $file --timeout=2` and `val_system` now returns 2048.

None of my attempts bared any fruit and I have come here to seek guidance. How can I make `val_system` / `system()` return what `echo "$?"` returns ?

How can I get the return value of `wget` from the script into an `int` variable that's inside the C++ program that calls the script ?

Comment: do you use macos?

Comment: No. It's `Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: See [returning multiples of 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375514/call-system-return-256)

Comment: I tested the same on `macos` and `freebsd`, and yea this was new to see return values in multiples of 256. So what I see is when I do `exit 1`, it returns 256, when `exit 2`, it returns 512 and so on. Check one of those answers in the link above, it explains the reason.

Comment: Great catch ! You may be right. I get 2048 as exit status, which means 256*8. And 8 is the "real" exit status of `wget`. I will test it more. I think you can formulate an answer based on this.

Comment: Yes. This is correct ! I have tried different exit status and they are all multiples of 256.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer value `system()` returned contains extra information about executed command's status along with its exit code, see [system()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) and [Status Information](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_13). You need to extract exit code using `WEXITSTATUS` macro, like:

```
std::cout << "System return value: " << WEXITSTATUS(val_system) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Uhm... I have written in the question that I have already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: That is the whole script and it does not return what it should. That's what I am saying. That's why I have posted here.

Comment: As I wrote in the question: if I enter an incorrect URL, `echo "$?"` returns 8 and if I delete `echo "$?"` then `system()` will return 2048

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199561/discussion-between-bleah1-and-oguz-ismail).

Comment: You should've kept the other answer as well, because it is correct

Comment: @bleah1 yeah, but it wasn't addressing the core issue

Answer (score 3):

If you want to echo the status *and* return it, you will need to save the value of `$?` to a variable, and exit with it explicitly.

```
wget_output=$(wget -q -i "$line" -O $file --timeout=2)
status=$?
...
echo $status
...
exit $status
```

If you don't need to execute `echo` or any other command between the call to `wget` and the end of the script, you can rely on the script exiting with the last status (i.e the one corresponding to the call to `wget) implicitly.

Comment: Will try that `exit` stuff, but in the mean time, I still don't understand why `system()` doesn't return the proper value even with `echo "$"` deleted.