# Return code of system() = 256

Tags: swift, macos, system, return-value

I use system() for executing a shell command in Swift.
As read in the documentation return value should be 0, if successful or -1 if it failed. But I get 256 and execution seems to be successful.

There are some other questions related to magical value "256" but with different languages and no solutions/explanations.

I would add a comparison to 256 for success, but it would be better to know what happened and what else should be checked for success.

Added: 
Yes, I read this. And there are a lot of assumptions and guesses, but no explicit solution. And it is not Swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing shell script with system() returns 256. What does that mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736320/executing-shell-script-with-system-returns-256-what-does-that-mean)

Comment: Isn't `system()` deprecated nowadays, in favor of `posix_spawn()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: Yes, I read this. And there are a lot of assumptions and guesses, but no explicit solution. And it is not Swift.

Comment: A self-contained, reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: Realy simple, like 

let err = system("ls")
if err == 0 || err == 256 { ... }

Comment: `system("ls")` returns `0` on my computer.