# Return value of a command line program

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point

I have an issue and I don't know my program is correct or not.
Please let me know your ideas?

Issue: Create a process file program in command line and the return of program is the number of processed file.

My program: in main() function I return the number of processed file.

Is it correct? If correct, how can I get this value from another program?

Please help me?

Comment: Note that returning count of things processed as an exit status is dangerous, since the [largest value you can return in an exist status is 255](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808541/any-benefit-in-using-wexitstatus-macro-in-c-over-division-by-256-on-exit-status).

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use return. A common return value for Success is 0, and anything else is considered some sort of error.

```
int main()
{
 ...

return 0;
}
```

To get the value to another program, you can either use a System call, 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_(C_standard_library)

or use a bash script like:

Edited, thanks Evan Teran:

```
  myProgram; 
    V=$?; 
    program1 $V
```

Comment: That's not how you get the return value of a program that will assign the output (as in `stdout` to `$v`). To get the return value you should do this: `myProgram; V=$?; program1 $V`

Answer (score 3):

main() can return "exit code" to OS by using exit(code) function

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Program will exit";
    exit(1); // Returns 1 to the operating system

    cout<<"This line is never executed";
}
```

Then in caller program, you can check returned exit code, for example (caller is a batch file):

```
@echo off
call yourapp.exe
echo Exit Code = %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The result code of the program is the return value of the `main` function.