# Weirdly changing status codes

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a simple program to test exit codes:

```
int main() { 
    return 2000;
}
```

In the terminal if I run the program then type:

```
echo $?
```

the terminal replies with `208`. What? Why would it do that?

Comment: Exit codes only range through 256? Why force main to return `int` then?

Comment: Because the language says so... (the language requires `main` to return an `int`)

Comment: @Mystical I think the OP was getting at why the _standard_ says so.

Comment: Inherited from 'C', for the same reason that "toupper" etc take an int when the values are actually chars. 'int' was at one point a catch-all, generic, "a number". It's gotten a lot bigger since then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the return value of `main` is an `int` (generally 32 bits), only 8 bits of the exit code are communicated out to the rest of the operating system.

As [Mystical pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106949/weirdly-changing-status-codes#comment28251216_19106949), `2000 % 256 = 208`.

*In Linux*, a parent process retrieves the status of a child process via a call to [`wait` or `waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) (usually after the child [`exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit)s). That call provides a status value - encoded in this `int` is the exit code of the child, along with several other fields, indicating if/how the child exited, etc. The exit code is extracted via the [`WEXITSTATUS`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/topic/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpc2/cpp_wexitstatus.html) macro.

```
int status;
waitpid(childpid, &status, 0);
if (WIFEXITED(status))
    printf("Child exited with code %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
```

It's interesting to note that I don't really see this mentioned in any of the `man` pages, though!

But it's very apparent if we take a look at the kernel:

In [`kernel/exit.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.2/kernel/exit.c#L888), we see where the `exit` system call is defined:

```
888  SYSCALL_DEFINE1(exit, int, error_code)
889  {
890      do_exit((error_code&0xff)<<8);
891  }
```

You can see right there, that the `int` error code is truncated to eight bits, and stuffed into bits 15:8 of the code passed to [`do_exit`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.2/kernel/exit.c#L696).

Related questions:

- [Any benefit in using WEXITSTATUS macro in C over division by 256 on exit() status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808541/any-benefit-in-using-wexitstatus-macro-in-c-over-division-by-256-on-exit-statu)

Answer (score 2):

UNIX error codes are a byte big, so your value is chopped down to its remainder mod 256, namely 208.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard only defines three return codes: `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. (Normally, `EXIT_SUCCESS` *is* `0`, but I don't think that is technically required.)

If the status return is `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, then "an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned [to the host environment]". If it's `EXIT_FAILURE`, then "unsuccessful termination" is returned.

Any other return code is implementation-defined. Your implementation defines that a status return of 2000 returns 208 to the host-environment. It's completely within it's rights to do so.